# Substitute variable inside single quotes - python 3x

Tags: python-3.x

I need to substitute variable `g_key` in the below line. Putting it in {} does not seem to work.
Could anyone suggest? Thanks

```
d.setopt(pycurl.HTTPHEADER, ['Accept: application/json', 'Authorization: Bearer g_key'])
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can try f string if you use Python 3.6 or above

```
f'Authorization: Bearer {}'
```

or format method in must kind of versions.

```
'Authorization: Bearer {g_key}'.format(g_key="some values")
```

Answer (score 0):

you can use `format` or `f-strings`, using format

`d.setopt(pycurl.HTTPHEADER, ['Accept: application/json', 'Authorization: Bearer {}'.format(g_key)])`

Answer (score 0):

make it a formatted string e.g, f"Hello my name is {name}".